# MySQL one to many subselect max UNIX_TIMESTAMP() from date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is working well apart from getting the max date from the comments related to a post.

So what im trying to do is:

- Relationship: 1 post to many comments
- Get the 'latest comment date' for each post in UNIX_TIMESTAMP() using max()
- Sort the whole query by either the 'latest post date' or the 'latest comment date'. So sort by 'latest post date' or 'latest comment date'depending per row.
- So the record at the top is either the latest post or if a post has a comment that is later then any post that would go to the top.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Query that works without getting max latest comment date and sorting by latest

```
SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title AS thetitle,wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,wallposts.date_created,wallposts.course 
        FROM wallposts,wallusers
        where (
        wallposts.userid =4276 OR
        wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%' OR
        EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wallcomments WHERE wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id AND wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%')
        ) 
        AND wallusers.mem_id = wallposts.userid
        order by wallposts.p_id desc
```

The one i have tried to solve the issue but fails:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,wallposts.type,wallposts.value,wallposts.media,wallposts.youtube,wallposts.post_type,wallposts.tagedpersons,wallposts.title AS thetitle,wallposts.url,wallposts.description,wallposts.cur_image,wallposts.uip,wallposts.likes,wallposts.userid,wallposts.posted_by,wallposts.post as postdata,wallusers.*, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,wallposts.date_created,wallposts.course 
                FROM wallposts,wallusers
                JOIN wallusers wu on wallposts.userid = wu.mem_id
                LEFT JOIN wallcomments wc ON wc.post_id(SELECT date_created as commentdate_created, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - max(date_created) as latestcomment
                FROM wallcomments wc WHERE wallposts.p_id = wc.post_id LIMIT 1)
                where (
                wallposts.userid = 4276 OR
                wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%' OR
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM wallcomments WHERE wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id AND wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%')
                ) 
                order by greatest(latestcomment, TimeSpent) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The query itself looks a bit strange to me - the LEFT JOIN seems to be corrupted, please check it again:

```
SELECT 
      DISTINCT wallposts.p_id,
      wallposts.type,
      wallposts.value,
      wallposts.media,
      wallposts.youtube,
      wallposts.post_type,
      wallposts.tagedpersons,
      wallposts.title AS thetitle,
      wallposts.url,
      wallposts.description,
      wallposts.cur_image,
      wallposts.uip,
      wallposts.likes,
      wallposts.userid,
      wallposts.posted_by,
      wallposts.post as postdata,
      wallusers.*,
      UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - wallposts.date_created AS TimeSpent,
      wallposts.date_created,
      wallposts.course 
FROM wallposts, wallusers
      JOIN wallusers wu 
            on wallposts.userid = wu.mem_id
      LEFT JOIN wallcomments wc 
            ON wc.post_id (
                  SELECT 
                        date_created as commentdate_created, 
                        UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - max(date_created) as latestcomment
                  FROM wallcomments wc 
                  WHERE wallposts.p_id = wc.post_id LIMIT 1
            )
WHERE (
            wallposts.userid = 4276 OR
            wallposts.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%' OR
            EXISTS (
                  SELECT * 
                  FROM wallcomments 
                  WHERE wallposts.p_id = wallcomments.post_id 
                        AND wallcomments.tagedpersons LIKE '%4276%'
            )
      )
order by greatest(latestcomment, TimeSpent) DESC
```

Comment: What do you mean LEFT JOIN seems to be corrupted. Im not sure if i even need to use LEFT JOIN. I copied and pasted you code into phpmyadmin here is the error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT date_created as commentdate_created, ' at line 27

Comment: All I did - formatted the code given so that it would be readable

Comment: OK, doesn't really help Ive already read it as I wrote it. Why not just edit my question and reformat.